# “Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction Class” vlookup in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'll just say right off the bat that I'm a newb in coding overall. I've learned a lot along the way creating various things at work for myself and I'm learning all the time.

The problem I have right now is with a loop using application.vlookup(...). I've done a lot of searching around but I gave up because I couldn't get anything to work. I've removed the .WorksheetFunction part from the original code because apparently it doesn't change anything but at least it doesn't give VBA errors when a value is not found and acts similar to the normal function (gives #N/A).

So in the below code I have my data in column A which I need to convert using vlookup on a Query in another worksheet (and put that in the same sheet as the data, in column C).

```
Sub vlookup() 

Dim wsdata As Worksheet 
Dim lr As Long 
Dim rng As Range 

Set wsdata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 
wsdata.Columns("C").Delete 
wsdata.Range("D1") = "Correct number"
lr = wsdata.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
Set rng = wsdata.Range("A1:D" & lr) 

Dim lrQuery As Long, iNr As Long 
Dim wsQuery As Worksheet 
Dim LookUpRange As Range 
Set wsQuery = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IDMquery") 
lrQuery = wsQuery.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
Set LookUpRange = wsQuery.Range("D:F") 

For iNr = 2 To lr 
    wsdata.Cells(iNr, 4).Value = Application.VLookup(wsdata.Cells(iNr, 1).Value, LookUpRange, 3, 0) 
Next iNr 

End Sub
```

I have to add that there are some issues with the formatting (or whatever they are), because the original data is external. Eg. for "17935" VarType would give 8 (string) instead of a numeric type.

In the spreadsheet it's easy to fix it with the double unary and the following formula works correctly:

```
=VLOOKUP(--A2,IDMquery!D:F,3,false)
```

Of course I could use a helper column and just use that, which might be an option if I can't do it any other way, but I would prefer strictly within VBA.

Do you guys know if this is fixable?

Cheers!

EDIT: Btw, I also changed the formatting of column A to "0" in VBA but it doesn't actually want to change these values to numeric, not sure why.

Comment: You can do the same in vba `--wsdata.Cells(iNr, 1).Value` or `Val(wsdata.Cells(iNr, 1).Value)`

Comment: Oh... well then it was a lot of concerns about not really much. Both work obviously, thank you!
If you want, post it as an answer so I can mark it.